# How can I change the colour of this matplotlib heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data here is arbitrary, it's only being used to show the issues I'm having. I need the contrast of [this heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0446.png) to be higher, ideally each square would be white if it contained a "-1" and black if it was above this. So far [the documentation I've found](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) for different colour schemes shows them as gradients and it isn't clear to me if these can be manipulated in a way that every number above "-1" would be black and all "-1"s would be white.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

road=np.array([[-1 , -1 , -1 , 1 , -1 , 4 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 4 , -1 , 1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 ],
               [-1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , 2 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 4 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 ],
               [-1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 3 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1],
               [-1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 4 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5],
               [-1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , 5 , -1]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(road)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(20))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(5))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

for i in range(5):
   for j in range(20):
       if road[i,j] > -1:
        text = ax.text(j, i, road[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="black")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.imshow(road>(-1))`

Comment: `ax.imshow(road > -1, cmap='Greys') ` would give white for -1 and black for all larger values